# Applying filters to images for a video sequence

Tags: ios

If I have an array of images, and I want to write these images into a .mov file, when and how are the filters added to the image so that the effects are visible in the video file?

E.g. adding a transition between to images, how would this effect be applied to the image sequence as it is being rendered into video or how can one setup these transitions on iOS?